# How to add a plugin in a plugin Django CMS

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I have create a plugin like
[plugin_pool](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html).
But I don't know how to add another plugin in this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin needs to set the `allow_children` attribute, and then you can control what children the plugin can have, if you want to, by specifying plugin classes in a list of `child_classes` as you'll see below.

```py
from .models import ParentPlugin, ChildPlugin

@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ParentCMSPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    render_template = 'parent.html'
    name = 'Parent'
    model = ParentPlugin
    allow_children = True  # This enables the parent plugin to accept child plugins
    # You can also specify a list of plugins that are accepted as children,
    # or leave it away completely to accept all
    # child_classes = ['ChildCMSPlugin']

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ParentCMSPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context


@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ChildCMSPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    render_template = 'child.html'
    name = 'Child'
    model = ChildPlugin
    require_parent = True  # Is it required that this plugin is a child of another plugin?
    # You can also specify a list of plugins that are accepted as parents,
    # or leave it away completely to accept all
    # parent_classes = ['ParentCMSPlugin']

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ChildCMSPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context
```

Your parent plugin template then needs to render the children somewhere like this;

```html
{% load cms_tags %}

<div class="plugin parent">
    {% for plugin in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
        {% render_plugin plugin %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The docs for it are on that page you've linked to;

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html#nested-plugins